# Why is the meta key is not working when using Emacs?

Tags: emacs

Suddenly, I am not able to use any combination of meta keys. The <kbd>Alt</kbd> key is not working at all in my emacs. Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: A quick workaround is that hitting escape before another key acts as Meta+key_you_pressed.  It's better to figure out what's causing the problem but hopefully this helps for the time being.

Comment: @Dason Thanks for the comment. It works, but only once. I have to hit escape every time before any Meta command. Weird. I wish I can find what is causing this.

Comment: Could it be that the terminal window is capturing <key>Alt</key> and attempting to use it to access it's menus (eg: File, Edit, etc..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this in my Ubuntu Terminal app by going in the menu:  Edit -> Keyboard Shortcuts and deselecting the 'Enable menu access keys (such as <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> to open the File menu)'.

Answer (score 0):

My VNC server had to be restarted with an extra option `-compatiblekbd` like this example:

```
vncserver -geometry 2549x1476 :17 -compatiblekbd
```

Once I added that and restarted my server, the meta key started working as I expect it to.

Note that `-compatiblekbd` must come after the display number (e.g. `:17`) or it is interpreted as an argument to `-compatiblekbd`.

Answer (score 0):

On Gnome 42.4+ you have a keyboard setting that might be enabled by default for using alternate characters on your keyboard.

Go to:

- Settings
- Keyboard
- Click on the "Alternate Character Key" option
- In the popup, select another alternate character key other than left alt

I choose "Right Menu" since I don't even have a menu key on my keyboard but you can choose anything else besides "Left Alt" which is the key that is used to some shortcuts in Emacs.

I was having trouble using the Meta key in Emacs because of that parameters and now it is working as intended since I changed the alternate character key.