# How to use ESC key for Emacs

Tags: 12.04, unity, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, emacs

When typing <kbd>Esc</kbd> within an Emacs window under Unity (Emacs 23 standard package), the sound is turned on/off, but Emacs does not receive the key.

> How can I change (probably) unity such that the <kbd>Esc</kbd> and also the other function keys are interpreted by Emacs?

A very crude workaround that always works in (GNU) Emacs is to use <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> in place of <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

The question [Why is the meta key is not working when using Emacs?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87221/why-is-the-meta-key-is-not-working-when-using-emacs) does not apply because this was about using Emacs within a gnome-terminal, but I use Emacs directly under X.

Another option is to type <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> which produces <kbd>Esc</kbd> within Emacs and also works for the function keys; but I want the keys directly.

Edit: For some reasons that I cannot reproduce, <kbd>Esc</kbd> now works. It might be related to doing some `xmodmap`s.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you are having some sort of function-lock enabled.

A simple way of accessing the meta key is to use the <kbd>alt</kbd> key.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been solved, probably by a recent update of 12.04. That is, when I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> I see now `ESC-` in the echo area!

Edit: The problem comes back after some time. But pressing <kbd>Fn ESC</kbd> gives one the real Escape key...