# How to make xterm to send the Alt key to emacs as Meta?

Tags: emacs, xterm

I see that this question has been asked [multiple](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87221/why-is-the-meta-key-is-not-working-when-using-emacs) [times](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48759/alt-key-not-registering-as-key). The solutions given there in does not seem to apply to my setup. Here is my story:

I use ubuntu 12.0.04 LTS, with xmonad (not over gnome), and use xterm for my work. I would prefer to use xterm rather than a different terminal or emacs own window. When using emacs -nw, I see that Alt is not recognized. I verified using xev that Alt is indeed getting generated. Further, if I am using rxvt, I see that Alt is getting recognized by emacs -nw. I am using evil mode (as a long time vim user, and an emacs newbee), and I would really prefer not having my escape key rebound as alt (which was the solution given in another thread). What should I do? (If it helps, Alt-x on the xterm window without emacs running generates "ø" or if I run `emacs -nw -Q`).

Comment: If I'm not mistaken Alt is being read as M instead.

Comment: I didn't understand, you mean M rather than Meta right? Why do you say that?

Comment: Emacs Meta key. Can't you press M-x?

Comment: Oh, that is my problem. I expected Alt-x to generate M-x (as it does on graphical mode) but it does not do that on xterm for me. Instead it generates (ø)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As seen in the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xterm#Fix_the_.27Alt.27_key), you need to make Xterm to send the correct escaped key to the program:

> If you use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key for keyboard shortcuts, you will need this in your resource file:
>
> ```
> XTerm*metaSendsEscape: true
> ```

So, just do:

```
echo 'XTerm*metaSendsEscape: true' >> ~/.Xresources
```

And restart your Xterm session.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. So, if Alt sends escape now, how does xterm handle Escape? (Escape works too, I am asking for my understanding.)

Comment: @rahul I didn't say "Esc" escape, but escaped key press "^M"

Comment: instead of restarting your session you can also run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources`

Answer (score 4):

If updating ~/.Xresources doesn't work for you, do as the documentation says and update it in `~/.Xdefaults`

http://frequal.com/linux/XTermMetaSendsEscape.html

Comment: This worked for me in bare X server, like with `startx /usr/bin/xterm`, where `~/.Xresources` was ignored.

Answer (score 3):

There is an interesting alternative to managing your `.Xdefaults` / `.Xresources` files by providing the resource string directly as `xterm` command line option:

```
xterm -xrm 'xterm*VT100.metaSendsEscape: true'
```

This is handy, for example, if you have a custom alias for `x-terminal-emulator` anyway.